# Pygears how to fix interface to some value?

Tags: python, pygears

Let's say I have this gear

```
@gear
def test(a: Uint, b: Uint):
    return a + b
```

I would like to instantiate this module and connect port "a" to some interface but I also want to fix port "b" to some value. How to do it properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can basically supply the desired value directly while invoking the `test()` gear. Let's say I want to supply fixed value of `0` to the port `a` and some other interface, say `b_intf`, to the port `b`

```
test(Uint[8](0), b_intf)
```

Under the hood, PyGears will automatically infer the `const()` gear (from `pygears.lib`, so code above is equivalent to this:

```
test(const(val=Uint[8](0)), b_intf)
```

PyGears also supports partial application of the gears, so you could also fix the port `a` first, and then supply the interface `b_intf`:

```
test_0 = test(Uint[8](0))

b_intf | test_0
```